# Expected Value, elevators

Tags: probability, statistics

A building contains two elevators, one fast and one slow. The average waiting time for the slow elevator is 3 min. and the average waiting time of the fast elevator is 1 min. If a passenger chooses the fast elevator with probability 2/3 and the slow elevator with probability 1/3, what is the expected waiting time?

So I know you can just do it this way:
 [3*2/3] + [1*1/3] mins = 2 1/3 min

How do I do it using the theorem E(Y) = E[E(Y|X)]

Comment: If we let the random variable $X$ be 0 for fast and 1 for slow then $p_X[i]$ is $2/3$ for $i = 0$ and $1/3$ for $i = 1$.  We need a random variable $Y$ now to find $E[Y] = \sum_iE_{Y|X}[Y|i]p_X[i]$, but from the question, I dont see what we can identify as our random variable $Y$.

Comment: that is what i thought but the problem said to use the law of total expectation

Answer (score 1):

You *have* solved the problem using the law of iterated expectation (except
for typographical errors). Let $Y$ denote the waiting time for an elevator
(note very carefully, $Y$ is *not* the *average* waiting time for an elevator). 
Let $X \in \{1,2\}$ be a random variable that denotes
which elevator is chosen, say $1$ means fast and $2$ means slow.

Now, you are *given* that $E[Y\mid X = 1] = 1, E[Y\mid X=2] = 3$.
Thus $E[Y\mid X]$ is a (discrete) *random
variable* (a function of $X$) that takes on value $1$ when $X=1$ and $3$ when
$X=2$.  The expected value of this *function* of $X$ is 
$$E[E[Y\mid X]] = 3\cdot P\{X=2\} + 1\cdot P\{X=1\}
= 3\cdot \frac 13 + 1 \cdot \frac 23 = 1\frac 23$$
(You worked the problem under the assumption that the slow elevator is
chosen with probability $\frac 23$ and so got a different answer).